# Unexpected deletion of directory

Tags: files, home-directory, delete, locate

I find that somehow the Downloads directory in **/home/user/** is deleted.
on using
`locate Downloads`, it shows the existence of directory without any existence of files within.

now when I manually create directory named Downloads,
 `locate Downloads` shows the directory as well as the files the original folder had.

also there is no hidden Downloads folder nor can I access the folder or its files

this behavior is quite unexpected.

Answer (score 2):

`locate` command does not use the filesystem directly, it uses a database which is updated periodically by a background process:

> locate  reads  one or more databases prepared by updatedb(8) and
>   writes file names matching at least one of the PATTERNs to standard output, one per line.
>   ...
>
> **By  default,  locate  does  not check whether files found in database still exist.  locate can never report
>   files created after the most recent update of the relevant database.**

So I guess this is an artifact of the actual filesystem state and what `locate` thinks of the filesystem being out of sync.

To search the filesystem directly you can use `find` command.